# Fresh Install of 20.04 Plymouth errors at boot

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia

I have done a fresh install of 20.04 LTS 64 bit, all seems good and it boots fine , however I have these errors appearing at boot time .

```
[FAILED] Failed to start Tell Plymouth to Write Out Runtime Data ( x3 )
```

I have it in a dual boot situation with Win 7 , normal MBR/BIOS load no `UEFI` , I have used the Nvidia proprietary driver for my graphics and had to modify :

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` and remove `"splash"` as it gave me a boot loop at login as I have it set to auto login .

How can I Fix the Plymouth errors that appeared after removing splash in GRUB.

Please be gentle, I am not that hot on modifying Ubuntu or finding error files, but perfectly capable if it is explained.

**EDIT :**
I have started a separate question regarding just the TPM issues as suggested,
and changed title to reflect this.

Comment: You should only ask about one problem per post. The tpm thing does not see related to the Plymouth errors.

Comment: @ Organic Marble I have separated questions as you have suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Just ignore all the boot messages These are just caused as Ubuntu is not custom made for every hardware. Hence it gives these messages. If any of these message is not related to your hardware, then no need to look into it, and if it is related to your hardware, then you cannot do anything. So the best thing you can do is ignore them. If it is a serious issue, you wont be able to boot into Ubuntu.

So as long as you are able to boot, no need to worry.

**EDIT 1:**

On my PC I have the following parameter in `/etc/default/grub`

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash rd.plymouth=0 plymouth.enable=0"
```

After this run `sudo update-grub` and then reboot.

I think this will help. Try this. With this I see the Predator logo (I have an acer predator helios 300 laptop) and nothing else while booting up.

Comment: Yes it does boot fine , but I did really want to stop the errors and get a nice boot splash screen rather than a text type boot screen.

Comment: @Dink checkout plymouth manager. And you will need to enable pymouth service to do this

Comment: @Dink basically plymouth is the service that shows the splash screen. If you disable it then i dont think you can do anything.

Comment: @Dink see if the EDIT 1 solves your problem, before checking the plymouth manager

Comment: @Dink Even I use proprietory nvidia drivers, but i have set it to `Nvidia On-demand` under `prime profiles` in `NVIDIA X Server Settings`. As i also have integrated intel graphics.

Comment: @Dink Yes it is called `NVIDIA X Server Settings`. As you said it is a GUI on linux to adjust graphics card settings. In `Prime Profiles` I can completely disable dedicated GPU or a hybrid combination (as on Windows by default) or use dedicated GPU always.

Comment: Tried EDIT 1  , no good returns again to the boot loop issue , same as "quiet splash" so I returned to "quiet"and it boots with no password needed.

Do you run a password on yours , maybe turning auto login off would fix it but I don't want to input password on every boot tbh

Comment: @Dink i dont use auto login. I will atudy further and update accordingly.

Comment: @Dink i think there is some other issue. I tried enabling auto boot and I dont have any such infinite boot

Comment: Auto login boot and force Nvidia to be primary adapter ? Thats where many have the issue .You have Intel adapter as well which I think confuses the issue.When it happens you will instead of auto login (even though it is set as such ) be faced with a login page and it will allow password to be entered , but loops back to username again.Interestingly when you try and log out it says another user is logged in .

Comment: @Dink I have made an update to my answer. After setting the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash rd.plymouth=0 plymouth.enable=0"`, you also need to run `sudo update-grub`. This will fix it

Answer (score 1):

TPM is usually not correctly working on my thinkpads. Simply ignore those errors. You could fix it by disabling it in the bios. Since you're still running Win7 this is no option.

For Plymouth I'd suggest not to **disable the splash kernel option in grub**, but try to configure the service like described [here](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/how-to-fix-plymouth-read-write-service-failiure/136586/16). This is a manjaro link but you might get the gist from it. The `plymouth-read-write.service`is probably the service you need to check. 
So in your case you should use

```
sudo systemctl disable plymouth-read-write.service
```

Comment: Sorry, my answer was ambiguous. I've edited it. Try out the code I've mentioned

Comment: Thanks , am I right to assume to return it again I can change disable to enable in your code if I want to revert it ? I will go look at link again but there is so much code there it gets confusing.

Comment: Yes. Issue `sudo systemctl enable plymouth-read-write.service` to revert your changes. No harm done then